# Old drama anime about a dog and a kid

Tags: nobodys-boy-remi

I watched this anime when I was a kid. It was really old anime, probably 15 years ago. I remember very little about it but here it goes:

- It's a drama anime. I remember it was very sad story.
- I think this kid is a boy. He lives alone, probably orphan.
- His guardian, maybe parent, father or uncle died protecting him (not really sure about this one)
- This kid has a dog, and most likely a monkey, and probably has another pet but I can't remember about it.
- I think later on this series, one of his pet died or got an accident, probably the dog.
- As far as I remember, it was TV series, not movie. It aired long before Rorouni Kenshin in my local TV station.

That's all I can remember right now.

Comment: So when did Rorouni Kenshin air on your local tv station?

Comment: 10 years ago? so maybe more than 15 years ago...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Nobody's Boy Remi](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=2130) fits quite well. It's a drama anime from 1977 and is indeed very sad.

[image: Nobody's Boy Remi]

At around the midway point in the series, his guardian dies along with several of his animals, leaving him to fend for himself. He is always accompanied by his loyal dog Capi and has a monkey named Joli-Cœur. Hulu Plus has the complete series if you're a subscriber.

The anime was remade in 1996 as [Nobody's Girl Remi](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=1101) (switching the gender of the main character), but it isn't as highly regarded.

Comment: Wow, i never thougt that it was 70 anime. I watched the original one in mid 90, thanks!

Comment: @exatma - Glad to be of help! It's one of my favorite animes growing up and is directed by Ismau Dezaki, one of my favorite directors.

Comment: Ach. Helps to spell the guy's name correctly: Osamu Dezaki

Answer (score 3):

I think it could be [**Dog of Flanders**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dog_of_Flanders_(1975_TV_series)) (1975, 52 episodes) or [**My Patrasche**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Patrasche) (1992, 26 episodes), adaptations of [*A Dog of Flanders*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Dog_of_Flanders).

This is the plot summary of the original *A Dog of Flanders* from Wikipedia (**emphasis** mine).

> In 19th century Belgium, **a boy named Nello becomes an orphan** at the age of two when his mother dies in the Ardennes. **His grandfather** Jehann Daas, who lives in a small village near the city of Antwerp, **takes him in**.
>
> One day, **Nello and Jehann Daas find a dog** who was almost beaten to death, and name him Patrasche. Due to the good care of Johaan Daas, the dog recovers, and from then on, Nello and Patrasche are inseparable. Since they are very poor, Nello has to help his grandfather by selling milk. Patrasche helps Nello pull their cart into town each morning.
>
> Nello falls in love with Aloise, the daughter of a well-off man in the village named Nicholas Cogez. Nicholas doesn't want his daughter to have a poor sweetheart. Although Nello is illiterate, he is very talented in drawing. He enters a junior drawing contest in Antwerp, hoping to win the first prize, 200 francs per year. However, the jury selects somebody else.
>
> Afterwards, he is accused of causing a fire by Nicholas (the fire occurred on his property) and **his grandfather dies**. His life becomes even more desperate. Having no place to stay, Nello goes to the cathedral of Antwerp (see Rubens' The Elevation of the Cross), but he doesn't have enough money to enter. On the night of Christmas Eve, he and Patrasche go to Antwerp and, by chance, find the door to the church open. The next morning, the boy and his dog are found frozen to death in front of the triptych.

According to Wkipedia, [*A Dog of Flanders* spawns many adaptations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Dog_of_Flanders#Film.2C_TV_or_theatrical_adaptations). Considering the fact that you watched the anime around 15 years ago, and it was a TV series, it can be either of the series above.

Comment: Please flesh out your answer like this the next time you answer an identification question. Thanks.

Comment: @nhahtdh Will do; I think -1 is pretty harsh though.

Comment: The -1 is not mine. If I downvote, I wouldn't bother editing your answer.

Comment: @nhahtdh I see, my mistake. Thank you for the advice and expansion of my answer.